# How to evaluate numeric math expressions symbolically in sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I am new to sympy and not a python expert. I need to do some calculation symbolically, just like the below example.

Evaluate: C(4, 2) / C(7, 2)

I.e.
`2/7`

C(4, 2) is an express widely used in our country, it is 4x3/2x1. Maybe you call it Combination.
Similarly, C(7, 2) is 7x6/2x1.

1, Although I can write a function to calculate C(x, y), is there an existed wheel to do that in sympy?

2, No matter how I got C(4, 2) and C(7, 2), how can I get the quotient in the format 2/7 rather than a float number that is not symbolical?

3, I need something symbolical in a variable to use in other expressions. How to do that? Just like below:

```
x = 2/7
y = x * 7
```

PS:
I have already learned below is a symbolical way, but how can I keep pure numeric expressions like the above symbolical?

```
x = sympy.symol('x')
y = x / 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function `nC` which does this:

```
In [51]: from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import nC

In [52]: nC(4, 2) / nC(7, 2)
Out[52]: 2/7
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my first problem. But how can I store and use 2/7 in a variable symbolically if it has not come from nC(x, y)?

Comment: Whenever you say "x=..." you are defining x. In SymPy, `x` might be a `Symbol('x')` or a value like `2/7`. So define `x=S(2)/7` and don't redefine it as a Symbol and you will be fine. If you do `S(2)/7 you will get an exact SymPy Rational instead of a python float.